# Is this subset a subalgebra or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $n$ be a natural number. Let us consider
$$
T = \left\{ f:[0,1]^n\to \mathbb{C} \, \middle| \, f(x)=f_1(x_1)\cdots f_n(x_n) \text{ 
 for some } f_i \in \mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{C})  \right\} \subseteq \mathcal{C}([0,1]^n,\mathbb{C}).
$$

> **Question**: Is $T$ a subspace of $\mathcal{C}([0,1]^n,\mathbb{C})$?

**Approaches and thoughts**:

- My assumption is that $T$ is not a subspace  of $\mathcal{C}([0,1]^n,\mathbb{C})$, and I assume that $T$ is not closed under vector addition.
- I considered the special case $n=2$. In order to show that $T$ is not closed under vector addition, we have to find $f_1,f_2,g_1,g_2 \in \mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{C})$ and $x_1,x_2 \in [0,1]$ such that
  $$
  f_1(x_1)f_2(x_2) + g_1(x_1) g_2(x_2)
  $$
  can not be written as $h_1(x_1) h_2(x_2)$ for all $h_1, h_2 \in \mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{C})$. But this seems to be an overly hard problem since $h_1,h_2$ can be basically anything.

Could you please help me with this problem? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $n=2$. Take $f(x,y)=x^2y$ and $g(x,y)=xy^2$. Then $f,g\in T$. On the other hand, if $h=f+g$, then $h(x,y)=x^2y+xy^2$. But $h\notin T$. In fact, suppose that you could write $h(x,y)$ as $f_1(x)f_2(y)$. Then we have $x^2+x=f(x,1)=f_1(x)f_2(1)$ and $2x^2+4x=f(x,2)=f_1(x)f_2(2)$. But this is impossible since, clearly, the functions $x\mapsto x^2+x$ and $x\mapsto 2x^2+4x$ cannot both be is a multiple of the same function.

The general case is similar.